# Implementating functional languages for the CLR (Or, papers on the implementation of F#)

Tags: compiler-construction, f#, lambda, functional-programming, clr

Does anyone know of any good papers on the implementation of the F# compiler? I'm trying to generate CIL code for a simple functional language targeting the CLR, but I am struggling with a few aspects.

The differences between functional languages and CIL are making it hard to generate well-typed CIL code. I have solutions that work via type erasure, but I'd much rather find a way to generate CIL code that reflects (to at least some extend) the Hindley-Milner type system of my source language (e.g., by generating generic classes). Judging by the generated code from the MS and Mono F# compilers, they manage to achieve exactly this!

Comment: I don't know if it goes deep enough for you, but the [language spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html) explains how many functional forms are translated.

Comment: Maybe the actual F# source code will help? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/11/04/announcing-the-f-compiler-library-source-code-drop.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There aren't many academic papers on the implementation on F# - although the compiler is open-source, so you can explore the [source code](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp) if you want to learn about some specific details. (BTW: the F# compiler available in Mono is based on the open-source release, so it is essentially the same as the F# compiler available in Visual Studio).

The only relevant academic publication is Don Syme's paper [ILX: Extending the .NET Common IL for Functional Language Interoperability](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/69132/babel01.pdf). It is quite interesting reading - it discusses how the IL could be extended to make compilation of functional languages easier. Under the cover, the initial versions of F# compiler compiled to this extended IL (ILX), which is then translated to ordinary IL. The details have probably changed since then, but the core principles will be the same.

Comment: For functional languages in general, I would also recommend Simon Peyton-Jones "Implementing Functional Languages": http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/pj-lester-book/

Comment: OK, so I read Don Syme's paper and I'm sold on the idea of targeting ILX. However, I can't seem to find any resources for downloading/using the ILX assembler. Is it included with VS/Mono? Has it been dropped/is bit rotting?