# Where to get the F# ILX2CIL assembler?

Tags: compiler-construction, f#, functional-programming, clr, cil

I have recently been persuaded on the virtues of ILX (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002529/implementating-functional-languages-for-the-clr-or-papers-on-the-implementatio)) . In particular, I want to target my own functional language at the CLR, and this seems like the best option. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find the converter/assembler from ILX back to CIL. I feel like I'm missing something pretty obvious here, but in Don Syme's paper ([found here](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/69132/babel01.pdf)) he makes reference to several tools (such as ilx2cil) that I can't seem to locate anywhere!

Anyone else tried using targeting ILX? Where can I get the necessary tools?

Comment: I think ILX is implemented by .NET itself these days.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but what does this actually mean for those who want to use ILX then? The proposal in the paper puts the extension forward as a uniform way of implementing functional language on CIL (uniform representations of algebraic types etc.). However, it sounds like this is no longer the case, since it doesn't seem like I can get a standalone binary for ilx2cil anymore. The paper even cites interest from the Scheme/Mercury/Haskell communities for targeting .NET. Are said communities simply reimplementing the translator themselves?

Comment: I think you just emit ILX and .NET will execute it without you having to do anything else. The F# compiler must be doing this...

Comment: Are you sure? ilasm.exe raises syntax errors for all of the ILX examples in the paper.

Comment: Can you use `System.Reflection.Emit` to generate and execute ILX?

Answer (score 3):

Did you check https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/absil/ilx.fsi from the source code of the F# compiler?